# Return only first and last entry along with first and last date in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

My code below is working as intended to return the start and end times with a duration. I was tasked to add the first entry location and the last entry location but cant seem to get that sorted.

below is first working query

```
 DECLARE @first VARCHAR(20)= 'firstname', @last VARCHAR(20)='lastname',@guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @guid = (SELECT guid FROM  table
WHERE FirstName LIKE @first + '%' AND LastName LIKE @last + '%')



  SELECT MIN(localeventtimestamp) AS Start_Time, MAX(LocalEventTimestamp) AS End_time,
 Duration = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(LocalEventTimestamp)-MIN(localeventtimestamp),114),1,2,DATEDIFF(hh,0,MAX(LocalEventTimestamp)-MIN(localeventtimestamp)))
 FROM table
 WHERE CardholderGuid = @guid
 GROUP BY CAST(localeventTimestamp AS DATE)
```

Results of that query are

| Start_Time | End_time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-20 08:56:24.837 | 2023-02-20 16:40:45.210 | 7:44:20:373 |
| 2023-02-22 09:18:29.707 | 2023-02-22 15:29:47.213 | 6:11:17:507 |
| 2023-02-27 08:42:13.880 | 2023-02-27 16:27:43.010 | 7:45:29:130 |
| 2023-03-01 08:21:12.237 | 2023-03-01 16:12:43.477 | 7:51:31:240 |

These are the changes i made below

```
DECLARE @first VARCHAR(20)= 'firstname', @last VARCHAR(20)='lastname',@guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @entityguid VARCHAR(40)
SET @guid = (SELECT guid FROM  table
WHERE FirstName LIKE @first + '%' AND LastName LIKE @last + '%')


SELECT MIN(a.LocalEventTimestamp) AS Start_Time ,e.Name AS First_Location,MAX(a.LocalEventTimestamp) AS End_Time, e.Name AS Last_Location 
FROM table_a AS A
RIGHT JOIN table_e AS E
ON a.UnitGuid = e.Guid
 WHERE CardholderGuid = @guid
GROUP BY CAST(a.localeventTimestamp AS  DATE),E.Name
 ORDER BY Start_Time DESC
```

And the results are now looking like so.

| Start_Time | FIrst_Location | End_Time | Last_Location | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-25 11:41:21.217 | Stair 2 Out | 2023-07-25 11:41:26.273 | Stair 2 Out | 0:00:05:057 |
| 2023-07-25 08:27:03.257 | Office - 228 | 2023-07-25 08:27:05.110 | Office - 228 | 0:00:01:853 |
| 2023-07-25 08:26:32.423 | Stair2 | 2023-07-25 08:26:33.800 | Stair2 | 0:00:01:377 |
| 2023-07-25 08:26:05.000 | Stair 2 In | 2023-07-25 08:26:06.390 | Stair 2 In | 0:00:01:390 |
| 2023-07-25 08:24:41.200 | V1000_Emp_Gate | 2023-07-25 08:24:46.270 | V1000_Emp_Gate | 0:00:05:070 |

I am expecting the results to be

| Start_Time | FIrst_Location | End_Time | Last_Location | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-25 08:24:41.200 | V1000_Emp_Gate | 2023-07-25 11:41:26.273 | Stair 2 Out | 0:03:05:070 |

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and how to fix it ?

---EDIT

Ok i made a little progress but still stuck . I can now get the guid results i need but am having trouble matching it with the named column from another table.

```
DECLARE @first VARCHAR(20)= 'name', @last VARCHAR(20)='name',@guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @entityguid VARCHAR(40)
SET @guid = (SELECT guid FROM  Directory1.dbo.Cardholder
WHERE FirstName LIKE @first + '%' AND LastName LIKE @last + '%')



  SELECT MIN(a.localeventtimestamp) AS Start_Time, MAX(a.LocalEventTimestamp) AS End_time,
 Duration = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(a.LocalEventTimestamp)-MIN(a.localeventtimestamp),114),1,2,DATEDIFF(hh,0,MAX(a.LocalEventTimestamp)-MIN(a.localeventtimestamp))), MIN(a.UnitGuid) AS Frst_Location,MAX(a.UnitGuid) AS Last_Location
 FROM AccessManager.dbo.Events_149 AS a
 WHERE CardholderGuid = @guid

 GROUP BY CAST(a.localeventTimestamp AS DATE)
 ORDER BY Start_Time DESC
```

That returns the following results

| Start_Time | End_time | Duration | First_Location | Last_Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-26 07:12:33.197 | 2023-07-26 15:02:55.840 | 7:50:22:643 | EE2E1A5D-A9AC-4BC2-B9CC-1E9461B2532B | F5DA95FB-E938-4C94-9D17-F1DFDD1927EB |
| 2023-07-25 07:11:37.080 | 2023-07-25 15:06:28.110 | 7:54:51:030 | EE2E1A5D-A9AC-4BC2-B9CC-1E9461B2532B | F5DA95FB-E938-4C94-9D17-F1DFDD1927EB |

How can i join table a that contains the unit guid - EE2E1A5D-A9AC-4BC2-B9CC-1E9461B2532B on table b that contains guid -EE2E1A5D-A9AC-4BC2-B9CC-1E9461B2532B and name "Employee Exit" Only returning the name in the place of last location and first location when they match?